# Laravel - Composer detected issues in your platform after updating it

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So i just updated composer using the command `composer self-update --2`,
However, now my web application shows the error `Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0".`

I dont understand this because doing `php -v` gives me PHP 7.4.13

How can I fix this?

Comment: **Short answer** : add `--ignore-platform-reqs` after any command,

in My case, `composer create-project` casuses issues, but `composer create-project --ignore-platform-reqs` runs well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your terminal user's PHP version may differ from the server's version.

You may have 7.4.13 on terminal while having a completely different PHP version in apache2 or whatever server you are using.

Use `phpinfo();` in a PHP file and access it via browser to see the actual PHP version.

Comment: You were correct. Thanks a lot. The nginx conf file had php7.2 fpm

Comment: I did this and the printed version was 7.4.14 however this is the message I get: ```Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.3.25``` where else could I look?

Comment: @Eduardo I think your case is the opposite: do a php -v on terminal and if it prints 7.3.25 you'll have to change the terminal user's php version

Comment: @Hache_raw that outputs 7.4

Comment: Not a real solution but if you are sure your server is running the required version you can try `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 15):

### Here is quick solution that work for me

1. In you project you can check the platform check file
   projec-path/vendor/composer/platform_check.php

   $issues = array();

`after this Remove or comment the extra code`

2. Add the platform check option in the composer.json config section like this.

   "config": {
   "platform-check": false
   },

After that, you need to run

```
composer update
```

After the composer update platform_check.php will be deleted and project work fine.

Answer (score 12):

Please run this command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

If you add the `--ignore-platform-reqs` option when running Composer update, it will ignore restrictions. [Click here](https://hannesvdvreken.com/2015/01/18/composer-ignore-platform-reqs-flag/) for more information.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, please mention the possible consequences of using that option

Comment: @NicoHaase  i guess you are right. Here is the explanation. if you add the --ignore-platform-reqs option when you run composer update, it will ignore restrictions. Please refer this for more information -: https://hannesvdvreken.com/2015/01/18/composer-ignore-platform-reqs-flag/

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer** instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: Thanks my Hero, You save my life

Answer (score 3):

I simply change the file platform_check.php which was showing the `PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70400`. change it to 70300 (This is for PHP >=7.3) This solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after installing a new version of PHP on a server using IIS.  Not realizing that IIS didn't support verbs like UPDATE/PATCH out of the box, and these methods were being utilized by the website.  When a route was accessed via PATCH for instance, the new version of PHP was not handling that, so it fell-back to the old version of PHP -- and that's when this error presented itself.

Resolving it was simply a matter of editing the Handler Mappings in IIS.  I found the mapping that would point *.php files to my new version of PHP, and customized it so that it would support other verbs like PATCH

Answer (score 0):

Just update your version of PHP in cpanel.
I ran into the same issues and this helped me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29804054)

Comment: Update it to which version? If anything later than 7.3 is required and currently PHP 7.4.13 is used, this looks like a different error. Also, what if the OP doesn't even use cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is sometimes we forget to change the php version at server(platform) level, which is usually different from the dependency level or cli after an update or upgrade or even sometimes on a fresh installation.

- For anyone using cpanel, ensure to update your `php` on the cpanel to the one used on the application or during development.
- For anyone using `apache`, check your `apache conf` file for the project to make sure it has the same `php` version running in your cli i.e used by `composer`.
- For anyone using `nginx`, check your `nginx conf` file for the project to make sure it has the same `php` version running in your cli i.e used by `composer`.
- For anyone using valet check your current project' valet php version, to make sure its the same as the one used by composer, to change php version: valet use php[x.x]

Summary.

- Check your server configuration to make sure it has the same php version required by your application.

Answer (score 0):

inform required **"require"** version if desired or remove from composer.json

always put the ^ to indicate that the version can be equal or greater

then run composer update

in my case, it worked

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "App"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on my server. And it is mainly happened due to miss-match of php version between server version and your system version. I am using Nginx and checked on all my project configuration files, it uses php8.0 but on my terminal it shows php.8.1. Actually my application needs php8.0. The following steps resolved my issue.

To see all my running php versions

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

It shows the following page
[image: php all versions page]

Selecting php8.0 for my application. Run the command to see Nginx scripts are ok

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Then reload the Nginx

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Finally go to your project directory and update or install your composer

```
composer update
```

It has been resolved my issue, I expect same will resolve yours.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, yet I've stumbled on the same problem and followed the suggestions to use `--ignore-platform-reqs`. It worked, **but it's dangerous** because some packages might require the latest versions of the PHP version greater than the one you have running, and you might get in trouble with eventual errors thrown by incorrect package versions.

What I found was that, using Homestead, it was provisioned with PHP 7.4.*, 8.1.* and 8.2.*. After doing a `varant up` all the projects where running on the latest PHP version (8.2.*), which I didn't notice when they should be running on the version set in the `homestead.yaml` configurations for each project.

The fix was easy and safe. Navigate to your project root directory `cd myproject.test` and type `php -v`. If the version is not the one it should be running on, for instance, PHP 8.1, instead of PHP 8.2, simply change the active PHP version by entering `php81` (or the PHP version you wish to use). This should change the machine's PHP version to 8.1. You can check it again using the command `php -v`.

Now, if the PHP version is correct, you can do a `composer update` **safely**, and the packages that will be loaded will use the current running PHP version requirements (if they are available).

I hope this helps someone getting in the same trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Please run this command:
composer install --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo

Answer (score -2):

Problem Statement: "Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0"

**It'll solve your problem 100% .**

Use this fragment " --ignore-platform-reqs " while adding other pacakge without disturbing other package dependency .
for example

```
composer require giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php --ignore-platform-reqs
```