# Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0"

Tags: php, laravel

When I send a request from postman to my server I get this message as a response:

> Composer detected issues in your platform:
>
> Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0".

I have tried every single solution I have found but nothing has changed.

My `composer.json` looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
}
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.3.0"
    }
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform-check": false
},
```

Comment: What's your current php version?

Comment: @FreddyDaniel  PHP 8.0.2

Comment: Changue: ` "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0"` to  `"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0.2"` should work

Comment: Then do: composer dump-autoload

Comment: @FreddyDaniel not working!

Comment: @FreddyDaniel that would not change anything as `^8.0` means `from 8.0.0 to 8.9.9 inclusive`... Here [more official info](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339404/composer-detected-issues-in-your-platform-your-composer-dependencies-require-a)

Comment: @matiaslauriti in the link above I 'v tryed most of the answers but none of it works. for me, the answer below works well

Comment: `"config": { "platform": { "php": "7.4" } }` This worked for me. Your question itself has answer and it helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Composer detected issues in your platform after updating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143289/laravel-composer-detected-issues-in-your-platform-after-updating-it)

Answer (score 8):

You have already written `"platform-check": false`. It should work.

Try to use `>=` or double Pipe `||` or try the below command

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#version-range

> --ignore-platform-reqs: ignore all platform requirements (php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-*) and force the installation even if the local machine
> does not fulfill these. See also the platform config option.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md

**Update** :

After running above command, run below commands in terminal:

1. `php artisan config:cache`
2. `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: not working too. is there is any other reason for the same issue?

Comment: `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` is not working? What is your composer version?

Comment: It's not possible. You must run the command in the wrong directory. ` --ignore-platform-reqs` never returning the same error.

Comment: @Ravi I am not sure that `composer install` is the problem... the user is trying to send a request to Laravel and Laravel is returning that... it has nothing to do with `composer install`. It looks like more to me that the user installed with X version and is running Y version (not allowed somehow)

Comment: @matiaslauriti : It's definitely related to `composer install` as it did not run successfully before calling Laravel request. @Lubna Al Anis : Please check the update section in the answer. Please post the terminal error output in your question if you have any.

Comment: @matiaslauriti: It might be possible that the PHP CLI version is different from than web version but Laravel will never return such an error if CLI has successfully installed `composer install`

Comment: @ravi I walk with the update and it's working ... there are no more version permissions required.  but now I'm facing HTTP 500 Internal Server Error . Thank you for helping

Comment: @LubnaAlAnis: You need to write `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file and then need to run `Php artisan config:cache` to reload the configuration. After that, you can see the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

had same problem. had php7.4, 8.0 n 8.1

this is what worked for me:

`php8.1 /usr/local/bin/composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`