# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.22

Tags: php, laravel

Locally I have installed php 8

my composer.json looks like this

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
```

I deleted the `composer.lock` and run `composer install` and I get the above error.

I tried to add

- `platform-check:false`
- delete `composer.lock`
- run `composer install`

but then I get an error because I use `Constructor property promotion` in my codebase

So it seems that when I add `platform-check:false`, for some reason it runs on `php < 8`

P.S I didn't have that problem before, I just cloned my git repo and tried to run my app.

Comment: You can have different versions for web and CLI (command line). Make sure which version you're using with `php -v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Composer detected issues in your platform after updating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143289/laravel-composer-detected-issues-in-your-platform-after-updating-it)

Comment: when I run `phpinfo()` it shows that I am running `php 7.4.22` however, I tried to unlink `brew unlink php@7.4` and then link  `brew link  php@8.0` but nothing changed.

Comment: Did the output from brew show that the unlink and link worked as expected?

Comment: Yes. For the php@8.0 actually it showed that is already linked

Answer (score 0):

Your phpinfo() maybe having different version than 8.0. If so

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.0
```

Then restart your web server